# Project structure in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am starting to build a web app with meteor. As meteor documentation, it is very flexible about how to structure the files in the app but I want to make a better project structure for further maintenance. Is there any standard project structure which I can reference for my project?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/EventedMind/em

After following instructions you will get whole app structure, but if you are new to Meteor I'd rather keep it simple with if(`Meteor.isClient`) and `isServer` commands

Comment: Thank you Sindis. Yeah, I am new to Meteor and I will keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

My app structure used to look like this:

```
MY_APP/
├── client/
│   ├── html/
│   │   ├── template_one.html
│   │   ├── template_two.html
│   │   └── etc
│   ├── css/
│   │   ├── template_one.css
│   │   ├── template_two.css
│   │   └── etc
│   ├── lib/
│   │   └── util.js
│   ├── js/
│   │   ├── template_one.js
│   │   ├── template_two.js
│   │   └── etc
│   ├── common.css
│   └── main.js
├── public/
│   ├── image.jpg
│   └── favicon.ico
├── server/
│   └── main.js
└── shared.js
```

`shared.js` is where I declare Mongo collections that should be available on both client and server.  `main.js` files get loaded last - I have one for server-specific code and one for client-specific code. Code in a `lib` directory will get loaded before other files, so I put JavaScript utility functions in there that I want to make available to other JavaScript files.

Most of my work is on the client, where I have lots of complex templates, so I break out the client-side code into more files.  `main.js` on the client mostly has iron-router routes.  Event handling and helpers for each template are defined in the corresponding javascript file.

`public` is for things like images, favicon, etc. Only a handful of directory names have any meaning to Meteor, but `client`, `server`, `lib`, and `public` are among them.  If you use other directories at the top level, Meteor will treat them as shared.

After my app got more complex I refactored the project structure to look like this:

```
MY_APP/
├── client/
│   ├── template_one/
│   │   ├── template_one.html
│   │   ├── template_one.css
│   │   └── template_one.js
│   ├── template_two/
│   │   ├── template_two.html
│   │   ├── template_two.css
│   │   └── template_two.js
│   ├── template_three/
│   │   ├── template_three.html
│   │   ├── template_three.css
│   │   └── template_three.js
│   ├── lib/
│   │   └── util.js
│   ├── base_layout.html
│   ├── base_layout.css
│   └── main.js
├── public/
│   ├── image.jpg
│   └── favicon.ico
├── server/
│   ├── publish.js
│   ├── methods.js
│   └── main.js
└── shared.js
```

Basically, I began organizing the project according to areas of functionality (different templates correspond to different areas of functionality) instead of by file type (html, css, or js).  This gives the project a more semantic feel in its structure.  I also put all the server publications and server methods into their own files, just to prevent my server main file from growing to over a thousand lines.